# Meaning (likelihood, credibility) of "but the only trouble was that I'd never seen you before" in Our Town by Thornton Wilder

Tags: historical-context, thornton-wilder, our-town

From *Our Town* by Thornton Wilder, Act II:

> *Dr. Gibbs:* Well, Ma, the day has come. You're losin' one of your chicks.
>
> *Mrs. Gibbs:* Frank Gibbs, don't you say another word. I feel like crying every minute. Sit down and drink your coffee.
>
> *Dr. Gibbs:* The groom's up shaving himself - only there ain't an awful lot to shave. Whistling and singing, like he's glad to leave us, - Every now and then he says "I do" to the mirror, but it don't sound convincing to me
>
> *Mrs. Gibbs:* I declare, Frank. I don't know how he'll get along. I've arranged his clothes and seen to it he's put warm things on, - Frank! they're too *young*. Emily won't think of such things. He'll catch his death of cold within a week.
>
> *Dr. Gibbs:* I was remembering my wedding morning, Julia.
>
> *Mrs. Gibbs:* Now don't start that, Frank Gibbs.
>
> *Dr. Gibbs:* I was the scaredest young fella in the State of New Hampshire. I thought I'd make a mistake for sure. And when I saw you comin' down that aisle I thought you were the prettiest girl I'd ever seen, **but the only trouble was that I'd never seen you before.** There I was in the Congregational Church marryin' a total stranger.
>
> <sub>Wilder, Thornton. *Our Town*. 1938. [*Three Plays by Thornton Wilder: Our Town, The Skin of our Teeth, The Matchmaker*](https://archive.org/details/threeplaysbythor00wild/mode/2up). Illustrated Alex Tsao. Preface by the author. New York: Bantam, 1961. pp. 1–64. Accessed at archive.org 22 March 2024. Quotation is from pp. [33–34](https://archive.org/details/threeplaysbythor00wild/page/32/mode/2up).</sub>

My trouble is the words ***but the only trouble was that I'd never seen you before***. It seems to me to be quite unrealistic that the groom hasn't seen his bride before the wedding. That's not American like in my opinion, even in those days. However, it might have been the custom in the Congregational Church back then.

Comment: The Congregational Church is one of the most liberal denominations there is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would interpret it as him never having seen her look so pretty before.

It's a tradition in America that the groom cannot see the bride in her wedding dress before she walks down the aisle. So here, when he sees her in her wedding dress, with her hair all done up and makeup on, she doesn't look like the same girl to him.

Of course, at some level he would understand that it had to be the right girl, but as he's incredibly nervous and not thinking logically, she might seem like a completely different girl to him.

Comment: "marryin' a total stranger" suggests it's more extreme than this.

Comment: @MattThrower: You have to balance the likelihood that Frank Gibbs is exaggerating here with the likelihood that he married a girl that he'd literally never seen before. I think the first case is by far the most probable.

Comment: If they had literally been total strangers on their wedding day, he wouldn't need to tell her about it!

Comment: Yes, I agree. That **morning** she was a total stranger, not in the absolute.

Comment: +1 — This is *figurative speech* and *exaggeration*.  Frank means Julia looked so different from her normal self that (exaggerating somewhat, and combined with his nerves already) she seemed like a total stranger to him.

Answer (score 4):

Dr Gibbs does not literally mean that he had never seen Julia before their wedding day. He is comparing his emotional state with his son George's on their respective wedding days. Even though he is getting married that day, George is blithe and insouciant, whistling and singing without a worry in the world. By way of contrasting George's carefree attitude with his own wedding day jitters, Dr Gibbs relates a hyperbolic account of his nervousness on the day he married Julia.

Dr Gibbs says that on the day of his marriage, he had been "the scaredest young fella in the State of New Hampshire." He claims that his sheer terror gave his wedding an unreal, even nightmarish quality. Exaggerating for effect, he says that crippling anxiety put him in such a state of [dissociative amnesia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dissociative_amnesia), he could not recall even his own bride. He felt as though he was in a church getting married to "a total stranger."

He does say, however, that even in this state he marked Julia as "prettiest girl I'd ever seen," showing that despite his extremely cold feet, he knew that the marriage was something he wanted.